# systemd user journals not being created

Tags: linux, logging, systemd, fedora-21

Several identical machines all running Fedora 21 in a cluster are all exhibiting identical issues:

Attempting to pull a user journal with journalctl -r gives:

```
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

Trying journalctl --user -r gives:

```
No journal files were found.
```

Checking in /var/log/journal/[whatever] yields system journals (which seem to work fine as root) and one or two user journals.  Logging in as a user that has a user journal in this directory shows that these users can pull their own journal just fine.

It seems like journals are being created for some users but not others.  I can find nothing different about the users with journals, and it's not the same users exhibiting the problem on every system, despite identical /etc/passwd, /etc/group, and /etc/shadow files across the systems.

All of this worked fine on Fedora 20.

Comment: Not a programming question - voted to close.

Answer (score 30):

I believe this is related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/806469/how-to-allow-a-user-to-use-journalctl-to-see-user-specific-systemd-service-logs/814913).

I had this issue on Ubuntu 17.10. One of my users could view his journal entries, but another couldn't. The issue was resolved by changing the Storage directive of the `[Journal]` section of `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to `persistent`:

**Edit `journald.conf`**

```
$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/journald.conf
```

**Original Config**

```
[Journal]
#Storage=auto
...
```

**New Config**

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
...
```

After a restart of journalctl, all users could view their respective logs:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

From the [journald.conf man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html):

> If `"persistent"`, data will be stored preferably on disk, i.e. below the `/var/log/journal` hierarchy (which is created if needed), with a fallback to `/run/log/journal` (which is created if needed), during early boot and if the disk is not writable.

Comment: In particular, the root cause for this is https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2744: “ Allow users to read their own volatile journals”. TL;DR: only in /var/log [persistent], not in /run [volatile], are journal files spilt by UID.

Comment: I was having this issue on ubuntu and simply restarting with `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald` was enough for some reason

Comment: Didn't have any effect on our server :c

Answer (score 4):

Check the output of `id -u`, if it shows a number less than `1000` then you stumble upon [this resolved systemd bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/23679). It is [fixed since v254 release](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/27961/commits/97c621b72d8c5b5eb4bf7f177cd885bfc01518c9).

For older releases without the fix there is a known workaround for the case where you know the name of the unit you want to watch: the `--user -u foo` would need to be replaced with `--user-unit foo`.